# Calling a Firebase Callable Function from a PWA service worker in response to a click on a push notification

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, service-worker

My PWA and service worker are in place, I have push notifications setup, and I have a listener ready for when they are clicked. Now I want to call a Firebase Callable Function from within this listener.

From the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#handle_messages_when_your_web_app_is_in_the_foreground), the only Firebase library a service worker can use is Firebase Messaging:

> // Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
>  // Note
> that you can only use Firebase Messaging here. Other Firebase
> libraries
>  // are not available in the service worker.

So the piece that facilitates calls to Callable Functions is not available, right? Is the only option left for me to use the [protocol specs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) and call them directly? Using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) for instance. Any example would be great!

Comment: Hi @Oliver indeed, using FCM seems to be the best option for you, as it's even recommended in the documentation. I would recommend you to take a look at this article [here](https://www.codemag.com/article/1901031/Implementing-Push-Notifications-in-Progressive-Web-Apps-PWAs-Using-Firebase), as it provides some examples of how to achieve push notifications, while using PWA and FCM. Could you please give it a try?

Comment: My PWA already receives push notifications. My question is about calling a Callable Functions in response to a click on a Push Notification, from the service worker

Comment: Hi @Oliver sure, I understand that, but Callable Functions doesn't work like that with Firebase. As Firebase waits for the event `onMessage`, while looking to the file `firebase-messaging-sw.js`, you need to go with it. The above article and this other one [here](https://www.simicart.com/blog/pwa-push-notifications/) should help you working with FCM and PWA, as it's the option.

Comment: @I1b3rty Did you find a solution to this? I want to call a firebase function inside the service worker.

Comment: @chrisonline, finally I did not need it but as `fetch` is supported by service workers you could just call a cloud function via the standard REST API

Comment: Note: The doc reference no longer states "other Firebase libraries are not available in the service worker". They likely now do?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my sample on using Callable Functions, with REST API:

- [`callables.js`](https://github.com/akauppi/GroundLevel-firebase-es/blob/next.sep22/packages/app/src/central/callables.js)

This is the worker source:

- [`worker.js`](https://github.com/akauppi/GroundLevel-firebase-es/blob/next.sep22/packages/app/src/central/worker.js)

I chose to go this way, because it's not much harder than using Firebase clients, and I already had similar code available.